# how to access files which is outside the var folder in linux server in code igniter 3 project

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, file-access

I want to access files which is outside the var folder in linux server and my codeigniter-3 project inside /var/www/html.

and the files inside /data folder.

"/data/admin_assets/upload_files/Photos/nala/start_photo.jpg" that is the path stored in the data base so when i access this url I have get 404- Not found Error

Comment: What do you mean by Access? Access it via browser? Access it by opening it using something like `file_get_contents`?

Comment: @hassan Only the HTTP protocol will generate a 404 error, so I guess it's via the browser. Since the question indicates little knowledge of how this all work, we should keep the answer simple as well: _"You cannot access files outside your web root with the browser."_. No point of going into things like [the open_basedir directive](https://www.bencteux.fr/posts/open_basedir/).

Comment: @hassan there is images and files are stored. so i want to access via api or url in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) of PHP to read a file and return to browser.
An example can be use like this:

```
<?php

$file = "/data/admin_assets/upload_files/Photos/nala/start_photo.jpg";

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

And make sure you set permission so that web server can access that directory: `data/admin_assets/upload_files/Photos/nala/`